# Magento2 custom theme suddenly stops working

Tags: theme, magento-2.1.2, parent-child-theme

First I have installed a third party theme `Third/customtheme` (its parent theme is `Third/maintheme`) and parent of `Third/maintheme` is `Magento/blank`  on my Magento2 installation, then using `Third/customtheme` as parent, I have created my own custom theme `Anshu/mytheme`.
It was working well and I did some template modifications and all are working fine.
Then, to do some css styling modifications, I copied below from parent theme.
**app/design/frontend/Anshu/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/styles.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**app/design/frontend/Anshu/mytheme/web/css/styles.css**

```
.header .logo{width: 100%;}
```

And after this mytheme stops working and now when I am seeing the page source files are are coming from the parent theme i.e. `Third/customtheme`.

Comment: Theme was set in admin for few categories, cms pages and products and unfortunately I have checked in some those only.